# WooCommerce get total of additional fees added to cart

Tags: woocommerce

Depending on the cart total, I add an additional fee to each order

```
$cart_fee = 6.64;

if ($cart_total > 0)
    WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Shipping Insurance', 'txtdomain'), $cart_fee);
```

Now I need to get a total of those fees by date range by either an SQL query or a piece of code that would print these values out on a custom page.

I'm posting this question while researching but I am hoping I can get some ideas before it costs me hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two DB tables and their connections for you to start with.

[image]

Using the order_item_id, query to the item_meta table for getting the values.

[image]